# Connection of n line segments

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Is there any way on how to connect n line segments optimally or in any way? Like we can construct Steiner tree for points. The connection between two line segments may be from any point in the line segment.

Comment: If you want to allow the introduction of Steiner points, then this problem is at least as hard as the Steiner Tree problem, which is NP-hard: to convert an instance of Steiner Tree to an instance of your problem, just turn every point into a very short line segment.

Comment: Is there any other way other than using Steiner points?

Comment: Well, you could instead build a minimum spanning tree, which can be done easily in O(m log n) time.  In that case, you should compute, for each pair of line segments, the pair of points (one on each segment) that gives the shortest connecting line.  Then it's just MST computation as usual.

Comment: Will this solution be optimal? If yes we can just follow the proofs of optimality for the MST?

Comment: Indeed a tree is possible in which every segment is an edge of the tree. [http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196677485710280]